# Incorrect time value showing in Snowflake table for datatype TIMESTAMP_LTZ

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are specifying all our datetime/timestamp datatypes as **TIMESTAMP_LTZ** while creating Snowflake tables.

for one of the values in Oracle source **'0001-01-01 00:00:00.000001000'** we are observing that when this value gets inserted in Snowflake tables this changes to **'0000-12-31 23:52:58.000001000'** .

There are no issues with other datetime/timestamp values except this.

There is no changes and alter to timezones when the query runs.
Is this some conversion issue due to to timezone or bug at Snowflake side?

Comment: We can test this manually by creating a table with single column as datatype TIMESTAMP-LTZ and insert this value.

Comment: I only want to understand how the local conversion is happening, the data was moved using Nifi, but I can simulate this manually.  for all other timestamps there is no local conversion only for **'0001-01-01 00:00:00.000001000'**  . You can try this by creating a single table `CREATE TABLE time_test (timeval TIMESTAMP_LTZ);   INSERT INTO time_test values("0001-01-01 00:00:00.000001000");`

Answer (score 0):

This can happen based on the timezone set for your session/user. More details for Timezone parameter can be found here.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timezone

Please use below link to get the timezone set for your session/user/account.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#viewing-the-parameters-and-their-values

```
show parameters like '%zone%';

alter session set TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York';

CREATE or replace TABLE time_test (timeval TIMESTAMP_LTZ);

INSERT INTO time_test values('0001-01-01 00:00:00.000001000');

select * from time_test;
```

Output of the select query is 0000-12-31 23:56:02.000.

Comment: But this is not happening for other values ,I am trying to understand why the value is getting changed and not changing for other timestamps